# quasi element wise matrix multiplication in R

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

Is there an inbuilt function or operator to do the following in R :

```
a_
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    2
b_
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]   -1

columnwise( a_, b_ )
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   -4
[2,]    4   -3
[3,]    6   -2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to make the lengths same and then do the multiplication

```
a_ *  b_[,1][col(a_)]
```

---

Or with `sweep`

```
sweep(a_,  2, b_, `*`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `b_` to the appropriate transformation matrix by using its vector form in `diag`:

```
a_ %*% diag(c(b_))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   -4
[2,]    4   -3
[3,]    6   -2
```